# bashにハイフン1つのコマンド「bash -」の意味を教えてください

Tags: linux, bash

以下の通り `curl` コマンドを実行したのですが、パイプの後の `bash -` は何をするためのものでしょうか？

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
```

**実行環境:**
CentOS 7
bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

この場合、`-` は何もしません。無意味な引数です。

BashなどのBourne系シェルにおいて `-` は `--` と同じです。以降の引数が `-` で始まっていてもオプション（フラグ）として扱わないことを示します。

質問のコマンドの場合、以降に引数がありませんから、引数が無いのと同じです。（引数が無い場合、bash は標準入力からコマンド列を読み込み、それを実行します）

参考:

> `--` はオプションの終わりを示し、それ以降のオプション処理を行いません。 `--` 以降の引き数は全て、ファイル名や引き数として扱われます。 引き数 `-` は `--` と同じです。
> —— [Man page of BASH](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)

> A single <hyphen-minus> shall be treated as the first operand and then ignored.
> —— [POSIX sh](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html)

関連: [1文字ハイフンが特別な意味を持つシェルコマンドの例を教えて下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/32124/3054)

Answer (score 1):

この場合の `-` は標準入力を表していて、パイプの前で実行している curl コマンドの実行結果 (=シェルスクリプト) を受け取って、そのまま実行しています。

`-` や `|` を使わない場合、いったん一時ファイルとして保存した後に bash スクリプトを実行する必要があるので、コマンドを2行に分けなければいけません。
簡略化したい場合に質問のような書き方をします。

Comment: まあ '-' なしでもシェル (bash/dash) は標準入力からスクリプト読むのでこの例においては冗長なんですけどね https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32124/

Comment: `-` が標準入力を表すというのは誤りです。
ただ、質問のコマンドを書いた人も同じような勘違いをしていた可能性が高いです。
ですから、コマンドが書かれた意図の説明としては、これが正しいかも知れません。